# Need help Complicated MySQL Multiple Query Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not so used to using MySQL and I am having problems solving the right query to get the right result.

I have these tables

```
CONVERSATIONS
- id, name

MESSAGES
- id, message, conversation_id, user_id

PARTICIPANTS
- id, conversation_id, user_id

USERS
- id, username
```

I want to get all the conversations where the user is a participant of. 
Then the result will include the CONVERSATIONS_OBJECT as the parent object, the last/latest MESSAGES_OBJECT (only 1), and all the PARTICIPANTS.

Example result:

```
[ // PARENT ARRAY
    { // CONVERSATION OBJECT
        last_message: {}, // THE VERY LAST MESSAGE FOR THIS CONVERSATION
        participants:  // ALL PARTICIPANTS FOR THIS CONVERSATION
        [
            {user1}, {user2} // USERS OBJECT ARRAY
        ]
    },
    { // CONVERSATION OBJECT
        last_message: {}, // THE VERY LAST MESSAGE FOR THIS CONVERSATION
        participants:  // ALL PARTICIPANTS FOR THIS CONVERSATION
        [
            {user1}, {user2} // USERS OBJECT ARRAY
        ]
    },
    { // CONVERSATION OBJECT
        last_message: {}, // THE VERY LAST MESSAGE FOR THIS CONVERSATION
        participants:  // ALL PARTICIPANTS FOR THIS CONVERSATION
        [
            {user1}, {user2} // USERS OBJECT ARRAY
        ]
    }
```

]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  u.username,
  c.name AS ConversationName,
  pu.username AS ParticipantName 
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT user_id, MAX(conversation_id) AS Latestconversation_id
  FROM participants 
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN CONVERSATIONS AS c ON c.id = p.Latestconversation_id
LEFT JOIN users as up ON up.id = p.user_id;
```

Comment: Hi sir. Thanks for the quick response.. What about the MESSAGES though? Can't find it in your mysql code.